# Shortest path without given nodes

Tags: python-3.x

so I was given x amount of points generated randomly and need to find the shortest path for all of those points. So what would be the best method I could use given that the amounts of points could potentially reach a very large amount and the endpoint would be the final points of the given x.

Thank you

Comment: you need to branch out from your starting place and add to each node a number like takes one step to get here and then put all the nodes you added to another array and go through them and change the next connecting nodes if they have a higher number. Then work backwords from the final x node find any node in reach that has a number one lower than it and so on

Answer (score 1):

There are so many methods for the shortest path. Dijkstra is the father of the shortest path, you can use it for trial and error [dijkstra](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/Dijkstra.html).